# Android how to adjust sizes of images within HTML strings when I use webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html", "utf-8", null);

Tags: android, html, image, webview

This images within HTML strings are too large, how to resize them to fit the device screen?
[image: Here is the image]

[image: Another image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a bitmapDrawable to ensure the image displays the same across different resolutions and devices. So assuming you have variable bmp containing the original image as a bitmap, desire an image 150 X 150, and do not need to filter the original:

```
            BitmapDrawable scaledBmp = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(),
                Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 150, 150, false));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

max-width: 40%;
  max-height: 60%